# Flutter - PopupMenuButton customize on-press effect

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I have a `PopupMenuButton` with a custom `shape`. When I press the `PopupMenuButton` inside it, the effect of the animation for button pressed overflows the shape of my content, like the image bellow:

[image]

The code for the shape is:

```
class CustomPopupMenuShape extends RoundedRectangleBorder {
  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    return Path()
      ..addRRect(BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
          .resolve(textDirection)
          .toRRect(
              Rect.fromLTWH(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width / 2, rect.height)));
  }
}
```

I'm just building a rectangle with half the context width, and a `borderRadius` of 10. But as you can see, the effect width isn't divided by two.

I tried to find a "effectShaepe" attribute for both [PopupMenuButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html) and [PopupMenuItem](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuItem-class.html), but got nothing.

The code where the button is called is:

```
 Container(
                    child: PopupMenuButton(
                      elevation: 1,
                      shape: CustomPopupMenuShape(),
                      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.ellipsisH),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => [
                        PopupMenuItem(child: Icon(Icons.bookmark)),
                        PopupMenuItem(child: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart))
                      ],
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                  ),
```

Is something that I can do to customize this effect?

Comment: Can you share the code where the button is called?

Comment: Of course. I've eddited the post with the snippet.